# random number generation for the battleship game

Tags: c

i need to create a battleship game for my assignment, but i don't know how to initialize an array to position a ship with the character length of size 5 and how should i put them randomly in a board of 20 rows x 60 columns. every kind help is truly appreciated, thanks. this is the original array

```
void startShips(int ships[][60]) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int ship, last;

    for (ship = 0; ship < 3; ship++) {
        ships[ship][0] = rand() % 5;
        ships[ship][1] = rand() % 5;

        //let's check if this shot was not tried
        //if it was, just get out of the 'do while' loop when draws a pair that was not tried 
        for (last = 0; last < ship; last++) {
            if ((ships[ship][0] == ships[last][0]) && (ships[ship][1] == ships[last][1]))
                do {
                    ships[ship][0] = rand() % 5;
                    ships[ship][1] = rand() % 5;
                } while ((ships[ship][0] == ships[last][0]) && (ships[ship][1] == ships[last][1]));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? A C standard library already includes a random number generator and you're actually already using it.

Answer (score 0):

First you decide if the ship is displayed horizontally or vertically, and the max position it can take on the board, H and V, without going out of the board

```
#define ROWS 20
#define COLS 60

#define SIZE 5

int horiz = rand() % 2; // 1 is horizontal, 0 vertical
int rowmax = horiz ? ROWS - 1 : ROWS - SIZE;
int colmax = horiz ? COLS - SIZE : COLS - 1;
```

with

- `rowmax` is the last row on the board the ship might start to be displayed
- `colmax` is the last column on the board the ship might start to be displayed

Then you decide the position randomly

```
int rowstart = rand() % ( rowmax + 1 );
int colstart = rand() % ( colmax + 1 );
```

and you fill the board

```
int i;
for(i=0 ; i<SIZE ; i++) {
    ships[rowstart + (horiz ? 0 : i)][colstart + (horiz ? i : 0)] = SHIPCHARACTER;
}
```

Explanation: the array `ships` is `[ROWS][COLS]` ; if the ships is horizontal, the ship starts from `rowstart` and stays on the same row, while the column is starting from `colstart`, the next cell is `ships[rowstart][colstart+1]`, then `ships[rowstart][colstart+2]` until `ships[rowstart][colstart+4]`. (Inversely if it's vertical)

Comment: Taking the remainder of the `rand()` value is not recommended because legacy `rand` implementations have bad randomness in the low bits. Generally, the `rand()` value should be scaled to the desired range (using multiplication/division, not remainder).

Comment: There is indeed a bias as `rand() % N` is not uniformly distributed, but it starts to show in the long run after fetching many values ; not sure that matters much in this case. Anyway to get more uniformly distributed random numbers, even in the low bits, [this library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) might be used.

Comment: No, the problem is not that `rand` has a little bias. Legacy implementations of `rand` are **bad**. The low bit may strictly alternate 0 and 1, for example.